# Generating Interface Proxies

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

Ran into an issue with a class; I have a class that looks like:

```
public class MyPresenter
{
    public MyPresenter(IMyView view) { }
}

public class SomePresenter
{
    public SomePresenter(ISomeView view) { }
}
```

The custom views inherit from a base IView instance.  I ran into a situation where I need to create a custom class on the fly that implements IMyView or ISomeView (depending on some scenario) and access the model, and I was thinking I could use a tool like Castle DynamicProxy to do it.  But I'm not quite sure where to start, and I need to be able to create a custom IMyView or other class instance on the fly.

Thanks.

Comment: What should the custom new class do ? That's quite important. You can easily create a "dumb" proxy with Castle DynamicProxy, that does nothing.

Comment: I just the class to implement events/properties; if any methods, I don't even need them to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I needed proxies, I found this [tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial.aspx) from Krzysztof Koźmic to be invaluable.

Comment: I did find that, but I had a hard time digging through to find what I was looking for.  Maybe it's because it's late in the day :-)  Was wondering if there was one concrete article on what I was trying to do.  Thanks.